# Find multiple matches in two sheets and copy paste in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro for multiple matches in different sheets that will return all the values for unique id.

1. Sheet 1 contains unique ids and values, there might be duplicated values.
2. On the other sheet, there may also be duplicated values and will value corresponding values for the each repeating values
3. As output I need all the corresponding values for one unique id.

Contents of Sheet1

```
id1 isin1
id2 isin1
id3 isin2
id4 isin3
```

Contents of Sheet2:

```
isin1 value1 age1
isin1 value2 age2
isin2 value3 age3
isin3 value4 age4
isin3 value5 age5
isin1 value6 age6
isin3 value7 age7


<U>Output</U>



id1 isin1 value1 age1
id1 isin1 value2 age2
id1 isin1 value6 age6

id2 isin1 value1 age1
id2 isin1 value2 age2
id2 isin1 value6 age6

id3 isin2 value3 age3

id4 isin3 value4 age4
id4 isin3 value5 age5
id4 isin3 value7 age7
```

I tried programming this, but I got errors.

I tried to loop two arrays ie( range1 & range2) and try to store all values in another array (range3).

While running the program I am getting run time 424 object error.

How to get values in desire manner in an another array?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim varSheetC As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck1 As String
Dim strRangeToCheck2 As String
Dim strRangeToCheck3 As String   

Dim iRow1 As Long
Dim iCol1 As Long
Dim iRow2 As Long
Dim iCol2 As Long
Dim iRow3 As Long
Dim iCol3 As Long

strRangeToCheck1 = "A1:B5"
strRangeToCheck2 = "D1:E6"
strRangeToCheck3 = "f1:h22"

Debug.Print Now

varSheetA = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck1)
varSheetB = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck2)
varSheetC = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(strRangeToCheck3)

Debug.Print Now

For iRow1 = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
For iCol1 = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)

For iRow2 = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
For iCol2 = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)

If varSheetA(iRow1, 2) = varSheetB(iRow2, 1) Then

    varSheetC(iRow1, 1).Value = varSheetA(iRow1, 1).Value " Here i am  getting 424 runtime error"

Else
End If

Next iCol2
Next iRow2

Next iCol1
Next iRow1

End Sub
```

Comment: If you could possibly edit this post so that it includes the nature of the errors and perhaps some of your own theories on why it might be broken...

Comment: @Doug it is broken because it is  not a method. But i am not sure about it

Comment: It's so easy to do with access using SELECT and JOIN...

Comment: @HugoLemos Thanks . Isnt possible in Excel?

Comment: Is possible, but tasks like that are easier with access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, there is only 1 id# on sheet one?  If that is the case, loop through the sheet1 rows and read each pair (id#, isin#).

Then, for each isin#, you search sheet2 for isin# and get another pair (value#, age#).  Your now have a group of 4 to output.  You have to, of course, read sheet2 for all the isin#s, so put that in a loop.  As a simple example - (EDIT - a bit more code than my original version now that I have Excel with me to debug):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()

Dim counter1 As Long
Dim counter2 As Long
Dim counter3 As Long
Dim counter4 As Long

Dim firstSheet1Row As Long
Dim lastSheet1Row As Long
Dim firstSheet2Row As Long
Dim lastSheet2Row As Long

Dim firstColNumSht1 As Long
Dim secondColNumSht1 As Long
Dim firstColNumSht2 As Long
Dim secondColNumSht2 As Long
Dim thirdColNumSht2 As Long

Dim writeRow As Long

Dim dataVal(1 To 4) As Long

firstSheet1Row = 1
lastSheet1Row = 10
firstSheet2Row = 1
lastSheet2Row = 20

firstColNumSht1 = 1
secondColNumSht1 = 2
firstColNumSht2 = 1
secondColNumSht2 = 2
thirdColNumSht2 = 3

writeRow = 1

For counter1 = firstSheet1Row To lastSheet1Row

  dataVal(1) = Worksheets(1).Cells(counter1, firstColNumSht1)
  dataVal(2) = Worksheets(1).Cells(counter1, secondColNumSht1)

    For counter2 = firstSheet2Row To lastSheet2Row

      If Worksheets(2).Cells(counter2, firstColNumSht2) = dataVal(2) Then

        dataVal(3) = Worksheets(2).Cells(counter2, secondColNumSht2)
        dataVal(4) = Worksheets(2).Cells(counter2, thirdColNumSht2)

        For counter3 = 1 To 4
          Worksheets(3).Cells(writeRow, counter3) = dataVal(counter3)
        Next counter3

        writeRow = writeRow + 1

      End If

    Next counter2

  Next counter1


End Sub
```

I hope the variable naming convention is clear you did not exactly specify where your worksheets, rows, columns, etc were.  Also, if you are interested, look up the Range.FindNext method.  The help file contains a loop that can get rid of the second for loop.  If you don't have a lot of data, it won't matter much (but it is better practice), but if you have a long list of values, native excel code (like Range.FindNext) will run an order of magnitude or more faster than manually writing the for loop that checks each cell.

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question and I will try to get the answer right (I do have a job though!).  And again, I would not code it like this.  There are more elegant, robust, and efficient means of doing this job, but I wanted to start with a working solution first.

Comment: Thanks for your effort .I am new to programming as well as VBA . I dont know much about other functions . Could help in writing the code with functions .<br>While executing the program i got runtime error 92 .

Comment: OK sure.  Was there a message associated with runtime error 92?  Can I see the code you put in?  Mine is sort of pseudo-code right now.  It is not a full subroutine.  For example, you are going to need to Dim val(1 to 4) as int, long, or double (depending on the data you are reading).

Comment: OK - I got it now.  See the updated code.  Sorry, last night I wrote that on the fly because I did not have Excel with me.

Comment: Your error was likely due to the fact that I had named the array val(1 to 4) in the original code I posted.  Val is a function so there was a type mismatch or something.  It is now dataVal(1 to 4).

Comment: Did it work?  Please let me know if there were any other errors.  It worked for me.

Comment: Very sorry for delay in replaying .  i am getting runtime error 13 , Type mismatch at dataVal(1) = Worksheets(1).Cells(counter1, firstColNumSht1) .  I was not at home so couldnt reply early .

Comment: Are your values actually numbers?  I guessed that they were numbers.  Sorry, just make it "as Variant" in the Dim statement and the runtime will decide what it should be.

Comment: Did it run after you changed the dataVal() array to a variant?

Comment: Thanks buddy . it is working very fine . I came late to home so couldnt reply soon ,

Comment: Could u provide ur email id . Thanks alot for ur help q